# Launcher Auto-hide leaves a dark bar, doesn't display properly

Tags: 13.10, compiz, launcher, nvidia-optimus, autohide

I am using ubuntu 13.10, I have alienware. It has nvidia-optimus but ubuntu is able to boot up if install it in UEFI mode.

I have tried to auto-hide the launcher both with and without bumblebee but neither approach works. I put up links to the images since I don't have 10 reputation yet.

http://postimg.org/image/kf7gkt73j/

http://postimg.org/image/ajnsdukhv/

I'm not sure why this is happening or what I should do. I might have to change something on graphics display but not sure what.  I can provide anymore info upon request.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check your display: System -> Display and check laptop mode only.

And try to download Ubuntu Tweak. It is very good, and I think it will help you.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa  
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

Comment: I checked out tweak and didn't see anything I could use to fix this. There was only the one display checked under the settings. Do you know about installing graphics drivers? I was thinking about maybe re-installing them. Maybe that could help.